# How to fill depending dropdowns with jQuery and JSON?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have two dropdowns where the second one (#second) is dependent to the first dropdown (#first). Everytime that #first changes a request is made to the server to get the #second's options.

When I manually select a value of #first there is no problem, the problem is when I use jQuery to fill the form's data. I assign the json's data to corresponding form controls. When I assign the value to #first then I use $("#first").trigger('change') and then I try to assign the value to #second once its options have been loaded.

It seems jQuery tries to assign the value to #second before its options are loaded.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <label for="desCa" class="control-label col-md-2">DES</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select name="desCa" id="first" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Seleccione</option>
                <!-- Incluir catálogo de DES -->
                <?php $des=c atalogos( "des"); foreach($des as $des) { echo '<option value="'.$des[ 'idDes']. '">'.$des[ 'descripcion']. '</option>'; } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <label for="entidadCa" class="control-label col-md-2">Entidad</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select name="entidadCa" id="second" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Seleccione una DES</option>
                <!-- Incluir catálogo de Entidades -->
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When #first changes:

```
$("#first").on('change', function(){
    var des = $(this).val();
    var get_dependencias = $.get(base_url+'dsac/catalogos.php', {cat: 'dependencias', des: des});
    get_dependencias.done(function(dependencias){
        if (dependencias.length > 0) {
            $("#second").empty();
        $.each(dependencias, function(key, dependencia){
            $("#second").append('<option value="'+ dependencia['id'] + '">' + dependencia['descripcion'] + '</option>');
        });
        } else {
            $("#second").html('<option value="-1">Seleccione una DES</option>');
        }
    });
});
```

Where the problem is:

```
$.post(base_url+'dsac/cuerpoacademico/buscar.php', {clave: clave})
   .done(function(xhr){
       var data = $.parseJSON(xhr);
       if(data.msgID === 1){
           alert(data.msg);
       } else {
           llenarFormCA(data);
       }
   });

    function llenarFormCA(data){ //data is in JSON format

        var pane2 = '#pane2';
        //Here a #first option is selected so I trigger change event in order to load #second options.
        $(pane2 + " #first").val(data.campo5).trigger('change');

        //Altough #second options are loaded, always the first option is selected, not the one that data.campo6 says.
        $(pane2 + " #second").val(data.campo6);
    }
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think the options in `#second` are loaded when the last line of your code runs? The `.get()` call is asynchronous, you cannot guarantee that the request will have finished anywhere in your code, except inside the `.done()` function.

Comment: I don't know actually, but the point is that when #first changes, jQuery is making a request to fill #second and at the same time jQuery  is trying to select an option in #second that might not exist yet. What can I do in order to know when #second options are loaded so that an option can be selected. Thanks.

Comment: As I said above, the only time you can guarantee that the request has finished is inside the `.done()` function. You could simply move the code that requires the request to be finished into there (or into a function that is called from within `.done()`).

Comment: I did it @winterblood!! I found out that I can pass params to an event via trigger, so I passed a couple of params to the change event to select an option after options had been loaded with .done(). Thank you very much.